# JavaScript - Different types of function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, object

I would like some explanation about the differences among these approaches:

Returning an object:

```
function Calc1() {
  var main = {
    sum: function(n1, n2) {
      return n1 + n2;
    }
  }
  return main;
}
```

Returning a function:

```
function Calc2() {
  function main() {};
  main.sum = function(n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
  }
  return main;
}
```

Without return:

```
function Calc2() {
  this.sum = function(n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
  }
}
```

Once the results are the same (for these examples at least).

**Edited:**

I know that the first one returns an object, the second one can be used only using *new* and will return an object as well, the third one returns a function.

I would like to know the practical difference in the use of each one or if the three forms can be interchangeable.
Maybe in this silly example it doesn't matter, but perhaps each approach is better for different scenarios (Or maybe it is just a dumb question and I should study more...).

Comment: First one returns a function `Cal1()()`, second one, I guess you need to call the `prototype` node of the function for it to work on some browsers, third one can be initialized with the `new` keyword; more less like an object.

Comment: What differences do you need explained? Do you know the difference between an object and a function?

Comment: The function that uses `this` must be called with the `new` keyword.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You're pointing out the differences yourself.  One returns an object, one returns a function.  What do you not understand?

Comment: I edited the question and added some information.